# Inkscape and logo with transparent text?

Tags: vector, logo, inkscape, print-design, mask

I need to make a t-shirt with a one color design that is EASY as a .png.  But the shirt company wants it as a vectored .eps file.  I tried sending them an import of the .png but that wasn't good enough.

All I need is a red square with transparent text and a logo: a one color stencil that includes text and the logo.  But I am finding it near impossible to create with Inkscape.  I can't seem to get the transparent text to cut out (erase?) from the red background square.  If it's transparent, then all I see is a red square.  If I make the text and logo black or white, it looks fine, but I need a ONE color design with the color of the t-shirt showing through the transparent parts.

Can anyone help me with a simple tutorial for this?  I'm quite versed in GIMP but haven't done a ton with Inkscape.  I just need to make text and the logo and have it erase from the red background, rather than being a layer on top.

Hope this makes sense.  Thank you for any help!!!  :-)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to GD. I have not used Inkscape in years, I use Illustrator, so this is just a general hint. But what you are looking for is a way to use a _clipping mask_. Basically, you "cut out" the text from the background square. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite basic, actually.

Caution, I'm writing this without an inkscape at hand, so I may be wrong.

1. You have to create two elements (the text and the box).
2. Then put the text **on** the box.
3. Then select both elements, and make an "exclude" boolean operation (I think it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>).

I'm not sure, but step 3 may not work, if one the element is a Text Element.
In this case, select the text, convert it to a shape (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), Ungroup (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>), Assemble (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>).

Again, I have no inkscape to test it here, but read well the messages in the status bar, and search the menus, you will surely manage to cut two shapes ;)

Comment: +1 just tested it. To exclude both, a text, and a logo we have to combine them first.

Comment: Thank you SO much: this worked beautifully for the text part -- three simple clicks and it was done!  For the logo, which is a .png that I'm "importing" it's not working...I'm guessing I need to convert it (maybe?) to paths or some such thing first?!!  Does that sound right?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out!!  This worked great!  Thank you!